# Unexpected List Duplication using Sort with Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

EDIT: The solution is to replace the '(1) with (list 1) in the first (let...) form. This is because I was trying to modify literal data. Thanks for the help! (I would give upvotes, but apparently you need 15 reputation...)

This is my first post on this site.

I was solving some [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems today and I came across some unexpected list sorting behavior (well, at least to me) in Common Lisp:

I have a function that finds all of the proper divisors of a number x:

```
(defun divisors (x)
    "Finds all of the proper divisors of x."
    (let ((sq (sqrt x)) (divs '(1)))
        (when (integerp sq) (push sq divs))
        (loop for i from 2 to (1- (floor sq)) do
        (let ((div (/ x i)))
            (when (integerp div)
                (push i divs)
                (push div divs))))
    divs))
```

This function works great. For example:

```
(divisors 100)
==> (20 5 25 4 50 2 10 1)
```

The problem arises whenever I try to sort the resulting list:

```
(sort (divisors 100) #'<)
==> (1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50)
```

Well, that worked fine. But what happens when I call divisors again?

```
(divisors 100)
==> (20 5 25 4 50 2 10 1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50)
```

What? Maybe if I try a different number...

```
(divisors 33)
==> (11 3 1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50)
```

The divisors from previous queries are persistent after I sort the resulting list. If I recompile the function, I get no errors until I sort the resulting list again. I am assuming I have messed up somewhere in the function definition, but I am pretty new to Lisp and I cannot find the error. Could it be a problem with the nested (let...) forms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frequently asked.

You've modified literal data. You need to cons up new data. Use the function LIST or the function to make a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Could you be more explicit? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: @Lisper `'(1)` is a list literal.  The consequences of using destructive operations on literals are undefined, and `sort` is a destructive operation.  Use the `list` function to construct lists.

Answer (score 3):

Rainer is right; if it isn't obvious, the code can be fixed with this change:

```
(let ((sq (sqrt x)) (divs (list 1)))
```